# Xamarin.Forms admob video ads

Tags: xamarin.forms, admob, ads, video-ads

I use admob banner and intersitial ads. And I want to add video ads to the application. I have done a lot of research on the internet, but I have not reached the right result. If you know anything, I'm waiting for your help.

Thank you

Comment: You should change your question to ask something more specific or ask about a specific issue you ran into. Your current question is too broad. What was a specific problem that you have had showing video ads?